# Can material plasticity and fracture be explained by quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics

I don't understand the classical engineering theory of fracture mechanics. But I have read a lot of literature regarding quantum mechanics. The question is:

How to solve the equation

$(\sum_{i=1}^N (- \frac{\hbar^2 \partial^2}{2m_i \partial x_i^2} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1,j \neq i}^N V(x_i-x_j)) +Fx_1) \psi(x_1,\dots,x_N;t)=i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi(x_1,\dots,x_N;t)$

that describes $N$ atoms bonded with each other with interatomic potential $V(x_i-x_j)$, where to the atom $x_1$ a force $F$ is applied? I guess that I can use a perturbative expansion around the force $F$, but for fracture I don't know how to solve this equation.

And another question: Elasticity can be quantized (gives a theory of phonons), but I have never seen that materials with plastic behavior are transferred to quantum mechanics. Is this possible?

Comment: As a general note, while things are quantized in QM, in many cases quantizations are typically so small and not coherent that it is incredibly difficult to observe them unless you carefully construct an experiment with the explicit goal of demonstrating the effects of quantization.  This, of course, is why it took so long for scientists to come across the need to develop QM in the first place.  Plastic deformation, being macroscopic and irreversible, typically involves an enormous number of degrees of freedom

Comment: nonlinear elasticity can be quantized; one obtains scattering of phonons on anharmonic contributions of the potential energy term. It relies on a continuum mechanical description. Can I quantize plasticity in a continuum formalism?

Comment: Explaining dislocation motion fully using quantum mechanics would be, well, really complicated. Small portions of dislocation cores can be handled in simulations. That isn't solving the real equation. So, no, you can't and won't be able to anytime soon.